# Странная ошибка компиляции

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Привет, Хэшкод!

Сегодня натолкнулся на совершенно непонятную ошибку, возникающую при компиляции следующего кода.

```
using System;

public class Tree<T> : IComparable<Tuple<double, T>>
{
    public int CompareTo(Tuple<double, T> other)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

> Ошибка при обработке сборки
> "Model.dll": Введенное число общих
> аргументов не соответствует арности
> определения общего типа. Имя
> параметра: instantiation

Причём возникает она только в моём проекте. Этот же код в пустом проекте компилируется успешно. Так же замена `Tuple<double, T>` на `Tuple<T, T>` да и на множество других параметров тоже приводит к успешной компиляции.

Comment: - Попробуйте как-нибудь выцепить фрагмент кода из вашего рабочего проекта, который приводит к данной ошибке, поскольку текущий пример кажется вполне валидным. Может быть, у вас там совершаются какие-нибудь хитрые `typecast'ы` или подстановки `generic` типов.

Comment: - Нашел 2 треда с аналогичным сообщением об ошибке *(правда, в рантайме)* - [**первый**][1] и [**второй**][2]. Может быть, это наведет вас на какие-нибудь мысли.

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765976/why-would-this-code-complain-about-the-arity-of-the-generic-type-definition

[2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635126/passing-the-interface-of-a-class-throws-errors-but-passing-just-the-class-works

Answer (score 3):

Эта ошибка компиляции вызвана багом в фиче Private Accessors в Unit Test Project в старых версиях студии.

Падает на стадии постпроцессинга сборки, при попытке сгенерировать аццессоры для приватных свойств класса `Tree`, или для классов, использующих `Tree`.

[Этот баг в connect - won't fix](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/578181/unit-tests-error-occurred-during-processing-of-assembly-the-number-of-generic-arguments-provided-doesnt-equal-the-arity-of-the-generic-type-definition-parameter-name-instantiation). Фича Private Accessors [не поддерживается еще со времен 2010-й студии](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vstsqualitytools/generation-of-private-accessors-publicize-and-code-generation-for-visual-studio-2010), так что если вы ее еще испльзуете - самое время пересмотреть архитектуру и перейти на моки для тестирования.